# align rows height in flex table

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm creating tabular view using flex box.
But unlike html table, where rows are the containers for cells (columns) I need columns to be containers.

That requirement comes purely from responsive design, when on smaller screens columns can be stacked up on each other encapsulating rows inside.

The number of columns and rows will be known, but the contents inside rows will be different, therefore row heights will be different on adjacent columns.

I can't get rows height to match by pure CSS. I've tried different flexbox solutions, but neither gave 100% solution. I'm trying to avoid JS solution.

The closest I was able to get was using flex-basis and flex-grow attributes, but had to give arbitrary value for flex-basis and that made some cells much bigger than they had to be. Also flex box started overlapping content below.

See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k6bfyv1p/

```js
$(function() {
  $('#fix1').click(fix1Clicked);
  
  function fix1Clicked() {
   // Add or remove fix1 class to content-table div.
    var cssClass = 'fix1';
    var $button = $(this);
    var $table = $('.content-table');
    
    var hasFix1 = $table.hasClass(cssClass);
    if (hasFix1) {
      $table.removeClass(cssClass);
      $button.html('Apply Fix1');
    }
    else {
      $table.addClass(cssClass);
      $button.html('Remove Fix1');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/*** FIX 1 ***/
.fix1 .row {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}


/***  Main CSS  ***/

.content-table {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 33.3%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row1 {
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
}

.row2 {
  background-color: #d0f0d0;
}

.row3 {
  background-color: #d0d0f0;
}

.row4 {
  background-color: #f0d0d0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Known (constant) properties of the table:</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Number of columns</li>
  <li>Number of rows</li>
</ul>

<button type="button" id="fix1">Apply Fix1</button>

<br><br>

<div class="content-table">
  
  <div class="col col1">
    <div class="row row1">
      Column 1 Row 1 
    </div>
    <div class="row row2">
      Column 1<br />Row 2
    </div>
    <div class="row row3">
      Column 1 Row 3
    </div>
    <div class="row row4">
      Column 1<br /><br /><br /><br />Row 4
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col col2">
    <div class="row row1">
      Column 2<br /><br /><br />Row 1
    </div>
    <div class="row row2">
      Column 2<br/>Row 2
    </div>
    <div class="row row3">
      Column 2<br /><br/>Row 3
    </div>
    <div class="row row4">
      Column 2 Row 4
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col col3">
    <div class="row row1">
      Column 3<br />Row 1
    </div>
    <div class="row row2">
      Column 3<br/><br/>Row 2
    </div>
    <div class="row row3">
      Column 3<br />Row 3
    </div>
    <div class="row row4">
      Column 3<br>Row 4
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, modus invidunt intellegam pri te, possit tritani id nec. Cu summo oratio honestatis per. Eum essent accumsan qualisque id. Animal molestie mel te, nec at elit fierent omittam, nec option fabulas ea. Iudico moderatius ad usu, eu modo melius qui, homero malorum usu no.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, modus invidunt intellegam pri te, possit tritani id nec. Cu summo oratio honestatis per. Eum essent accumsan qualisque id. Animal molestie mel te, nec at elit fierent omittam, nec option fabulas ea. Iudico moderatius ad usu, eu modo melius qui, homero malorum usu no.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is to use the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property.

In the demo below you will see I completely removed the wrapper elements and created rows by using `flex-wrap` and setting a width on flex items. Flex items, by default, will be the same height if they're in the same row. In the demo I went with a mobile first approach where I ordered my markup based on column ordering. Then, in our CSS, when we hit our breakpoint we use `order` to re-arrange all the items into the proper row.

This could get a little harry if you're building your markup based off of a query from the database and the column/row count changes. Even then, you could quick generate the proper CSS classes and definitions as needed.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.c1[class*="r"],
.c3[class*="r"] {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
.c2[class*="r"] {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

/* for different heights */
.r1.c1 {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
.r2.c2 {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.r3.c3 {
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}
@media ( min-width: 600px ) {
  .flex {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .flex > div {
    width: 33.333%;
  }
  .r1[class*="c"],
  .r3[class*="c"] {
    background-color: skyblue;
  }
  .r2[class*="c"] {
    background-color: lightgray;
  }
  .r1.c1 { order: 1; }
  .r1.c2 { order: 2; }
  .r1.c3 { order: 3; }
  .r2.c1 { order: 4; }
  .r2.c2 { order: 5; }
  .r2.c3 { order: 6; }
  .r3.c1 { order: 7; }
  .r3.c2 { order: 8; }
  .r3.c3 { order: 9; }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  
  <div class="r1 c1">C1 A or R1 A</div>
  <div class="r2 c1">C1 B or R2 A</div>
  <div class="r3 c1">C1 C or R3 A</div>
  
  <div class="r1 c2">C2 A or R1 B</div>
  <div class="r2 c2">C2 B or R2 B</div>
  <div class="r3 c2">C2 C or R3 B</div>
  
  <div class="r1 c3">C3 A or R1 C</div>
  <div class="r2 c3">C3 B or R2 C</div>
  <div class="r3 c3">C3 C or R3 C</div>

</div>
```

Also note that I set extra padding on a single item in each column to mimic variable height content. On smaller viewports when the columns are stacked you can clearly see which items are taller. On larger viewports you when the items are organized into rows you can see that the height of the larger item is used for all items in that row.